# Cannot change app.message = 'something' in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, vue.js, haml

I was trying out vue.js through https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/, I have included https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js file in my view.
The First App example I am able to load "Hello Vue!" when the app loads, But when from console I try to change `app.message` it does not change the title. I have tried viewing the dataset as app.dataset it returns empty object.

Js.coffee Code

```
$(document).ready ->
  # initialization of Vue JS
  app = new Vue(
    el: '#app'
    data: message: 'Hello Vue!')
  app2 = new Vue(
    el: '#app2'
    data: message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date)
  app3 = new Vue(
    el: '#app3'
    data: seen: true)
```

View Code

```
.mapWrap
  .latLong
    #app
      {{ message }}
    #app2
      %span{"v-bind:title" => "message"}
        Hover your mouse over me for a few seconds
        to see my dynamically bound title!
    #app3
      %p{"v-if"=> "seen"} Now you see me
  - content_for :js do
    = javascript_include_tag 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js'
```

Comment: Please include your js & html

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech can you please review the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `coffeescript` is scoping your app variable inside the `$(document).ready` function. Try this.

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.app = new Vue(
    el: '#app'
    data: {message: 'Hello Vue!'})
  window.app2 = new Vue(
    el: '#app2'
    data: message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date)
  window.app3 = new Vue(
    el: '#app3'
    data: seen: true)
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/aJPOpE?editors=1010).

Comment: I have tried this as well before but still, when I try to assign app.message = 'Something Something ', it does not change the data. But when I try app.__vue__.message = 'Something Something ', it actually changes the title from 'Hello Vue!' to  'Something Something '.

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke I modified the code. Just expose the variables on the window and you should be fine.

Comment: This sure works, can you please explain why was I not able to change it before?

Comment: Javascript variables have scope. The variables, app, app2, and app3 are not available outside the function. Changing them to `window.app` makes them part of the global `window` object, which you have access to on the console.